# Ошибка "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4"

Tags: java, массивы

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4`

Собственно что-то не так со вторым циклом, но что именно я упорно не могу понять уже некоторое время.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array =  new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < length; b++) {
            if (array[b] % 4 == 0) {
                length+=array[b];
                System.out.println(length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Суть кода, заполнить массив, затем сложить все элементы массива кратные 4.

P.s. я почитал вопросы на форуме с такой же ошибкой, но я только учусь и понимать чужой код сложнее, особенно с командами, которых я ещё не знаю.

Comment: Какие данные в консоль вводите?

Comment: Например 4, затем заполяем 4, 5, 2, 20 построчно. Получаю 8, 28 и ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    sum = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < length; b++) {
        if (array[b] % 4 == 0) {
            sum += array[b];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку нашла. Зачем-то меняю переменную длины в цикле, очень глупо